# Angular upgrade to 13 breaking unit tests - "Error: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node"

Tags: node.js, angular, karma-coverage

I recently upgraded our project's application version from 9 to 13 and as a part of it also upgraded few packages used including chromedriver, node, karma etc. Now we are using node v16 and angular v13 and karma v6.3.11.

I have karma.conf.js setup with concurrency 10 and I see that unit tests fail at following step with an error -

> "Error: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be
> removed is not a child of this node"

I calculate test coverage with browsers=ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox

```
afterAll(() => {
    document.body.removeChild(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement);
  });
```

I tried using "translate-no" on HTML and meta tags and also tried bypassing this statement if parent node doesn't exist but still this error is thrown. I am quite unsure what must be causing it. These errors are sporadic but quite regular and are not exactly same in count in every run and its causing difficulties in fixing the issue.

Note: These errors were observed in the past as well in older angular and node versions but were less frequent. Now with version upgrade, they are observed every time

Comment: Is the line in the `afterAll` hook failing the tests? If so, then why not remove it altogether? You don't need to manually perform any teardown logic and chances are, the component has already been destroyed before the logic in `afterAll` executes, thus leading to the error you get.

Comment: There is no logic in afterAll apart from this line so chance of destroying it before this line are almost zero. Is it advisable to remove afterAll itself? I also tried replacing "removeChild" line by "TestBed.resetTestingModule()" but it didnt help as well

Comment: You don't need to explicitly perform teardown logic when it comes to tests. I think the `afterAll` logic is unnecessary.

Comment: I removed them but these tests are still flaky.. different number of errors in every run. Also after removing it, its errors like... cant get length of undefined which isn't consistent. I am really a beginner in terms of UI